# CordovaHTTP Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] (Ionic + AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app in Ionic using AngularJS Framework. I need to interact with a server so i use cordovaHTTP plugin (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP, I've recently used for a phonegap project) running the following line

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-http
```

When I try to run my app, this error was displayed

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cordovaHTTP due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'cordovaHTTP' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=cordovaHTTP
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15270:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15194:38)
    at module (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15268:14)
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17674:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=cordovaHTTP&p1=Erro…t%3A63342%2FaulasQR%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17658%3A5)
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17697:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17675:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17658:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17584:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14942:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:63342/aulasQR/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14963:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…%3A63342%2FaulasQR%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A14963%3A12)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:13380(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17697forEach @ ionic.bundle.js:13648loadModules @ ionic.bundle.js:17658createInjector @ ionic.bundle.js:17584doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:14942bootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:14963angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:14857(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:41671trigger @ ionic.bundle.js:16308eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16583
```

In my app.js file I defined a module like this

```
qrApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova', 'cordovaHTTP'])
```

Also in this file, I declared a controller for the server (with a basic example)

```
.controller("serverController", function($cordovaHTTP){
    var getData = function(uri){
      var username = "yyy";
      var password = "xxx";
      var url = "http://movilesbluetooth.php.info.unlp.edu.ar/alumnos/1";
      cordovaHTTP.useBasicAuth(username,password);

      cordovaHTTP.get(url).then(function(response) {
              alert(response.data);
              $scope.response_data = response.data;
            });

    }

  });
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `$cordovaHTTP` just `cordovaHTTP`in controller.

Comment: I know, i changed it to prove it and I forgot to change it again.  But also with "cordovaHTTP" I have the same issue.

Comment: Other people also face this issue when ionic comes into picture. Try manual bootstrapping of cordova to delay ng-app initialization. See this link https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP/issues/22

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa at least give credit as I said about bootstrapping in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i could solve this issue tring manual bootstrapping of my app.
Following this steps:

1. Remove "ng-app" of index.html
2. Adding this into index.html

   var pgapp = {
           initialize: function () {
             console.log("adentro de init");
             this.bindEvents();
           },

   ```
       // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
       // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
       bindEvents: function () {
         console.log("adentro de bind");
           document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
       },

       onDeviceReady: function () {
         console.log("adentro de device");
         angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document, ['starter']);
         });
       }
     };
   </script>
   ```

And at the end

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      pgapp.initialize();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```